# I need a regexp that fails in every character is outside [a-zA-Z0-9_] or if the string is only numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, html

The following JavaScript code returns false if the string contains only numbers or characters other than [a-zA-Z0-9_].

```
function validate(n) {
    return (!/^[\d]+$/.test(n) && /^[\w]+$/.test(n));
}
```

Is it possible to do this with just a regexp? I want to take advantage of pattern attributes on the input tag for validation.

```
<input type="text" pattern="...">
```

Edit: I also want it to be between 5 and 20 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`

This regex matches zero or more characters including numbers, at least one character that *isn't* a number, followed by another zero or more characters including numbers.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to write that I needed a minimum and the maximum length of string.

Comment: @Christian: I'm not sure if you can do all that in a single regex.